# What does "Push Channel" refer to in Azure.NotificationHubs Installation class?

Tags: azure, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I'm having trouble understanding what the [Push Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.installation.pushchannel?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_NotificationHubs_Installation_PushChannel) property is responsible for when utilizing the Installation class in Azure.NotificationHubs SDK.

According to the docs, it looks like the Push Channel represents some arbitrary identifier for the PNS system that a notification registration may be associated with, but I am having trouble finding any consistent documentation regarding how this value should be populated and how it can be retrieved when creating a new Installation to register with a NotificationHub client.

If say, an iOS client where attempting to register for notifications, and was responsible for creating an instance of `Installation` how would you go about populating the Push Channel property of that Installation instance?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a string value set by the app - set it to whatever you want.